# Extract Header Info From PDF Document Pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Using Java 1.6 and iText:

I'm trying to extract header information from a PDF document.  By "header", I'm specifically talking about something similar to a header as viewed in a MS Word doc, and not the file header.  This document can have one to many pages.  Each page will have a unique header that identifies the content of the page.  Ultimately, I need to separate the pages into individual PDF documents, then extract the header to determine the title of the document.  The header text will likely be invisible but will exist.

I have no problem with page separation, but I'm coming up short with header extraction.  All documentation I've seen talks about creating the header for a PDF document, but I've yet to see any info regarding reading/extracting the header.

Comment: The first counter-question one should ask, is the following one: is the header in your PDF files marked as an artifact (as in "Tagged PDF")? Or was it added to the content stream just like any other content?

Comment: Unless your document is tagged (cf. Bruno's counter-question), the header is simply text that might (or might not) be typeset in a different font or with a different size. Depending on the creativity a document was created with, such text might more or less difficult to find. Don't count on there being a 100% reliable solution...